# count Jarray in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, azure-http-trigger

I need to count data from reqst body in httptrigger function.Data is coming as object type.
I am deserialisizing the reqd body as shown below.Below are the object type data i am getting in req.body.

```json
{
  "Response": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Warburtons Medium Sliced Soft White Bread 400g",
      "description": "Warburtons Medium Sliced White 400G",
      "brand": "Warburtons",
      "ean": "123",
      "mediaStorageKey": "b",
      "maxQuantity": 6,
      "price": 0.95,
      "size": 400,
      "sizeUnits": "Grams"
    },
    {
      "id": "a",
      "name": "Co-op Orvieto Classico 75cl",
      "description": "Co-op Orvieto Classico 75CL",
      "brand": "Co-op",
      "ean": "489",
      "mediaStorageKey": "c",
      "maxQuantity": 6,
      "price": 5.5,
      "size": 75,
      "sizeUnits": "Centilitres"
    },
    {
      "id": "kl",
      "name": "Co Op Garden Peas in Water 290g",
      "description": "Co-op Garden Peas 290G",
      "brand": "Co Op",
      "ean": "678",
      "mediaStorageKey": "f",
      "maxQuantity": 6,
      "price": 0.45,
      "size": 175,
      "sizeUnits": "Grams"
    }
  ]
}
```

```cs
string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
             
dynamic data = body["Response"];
```

Till this i am getting data like below.

```
{[{"id":"1","name":"b"},{"id":"f","name":"j"}]}
```

But now i am not able to count these data which gives 2 in this case as i have to apply for loop. Neither `Count`,`Count()` is working here. I am getting the below error.

`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` does not contain a definition for `Count`

Comment: Can you post the full `requestBody` JSON (at least enough that we can run your `dynamic data = body["Response"]`) and get something similar to what you show (which, by the way, is not valid JSON)

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  If I take the JSON in your question and try to parse it, I get an error *`Invalid property identifier character: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.`*, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/FVmqgM.  The problem is that the JSON is malformed -- it has additional outer brackets `{}` that should not be present.

Comment: If I fix the JSON by removing the outer brackets, your code generates an *`Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "Response". Int32 array index expected.` exception because the root JSON container is an array not an object, so there is no `"Response"` property.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/KYJuhG.

Comment: My wild guess is that the original JSON looks like `{"Response" : [{"id":"1","name":"b"},{"id":"f","name":"j"}]}`, that when he gets the value for response, it becomes `[{"id":"1","name":"b"},{"id":"f","name":"j"}]` and that the debugger shows it with `{}` brackets around it.  Just a guess though

Comment: Your wild guess seems reasonable but a [mcve] would clarify.  Especially since question is using `dynamic` for everything which makes it hard to know what is happening by inspection (and possibly is causing the problem).

Comment: Hi @shashank shekhar, it works well in my azure http trigger if I use the code:`var count = data.Count;`. It could get the result `2`. What is your version of asp.net core? Also what's the data you post ,could you please share with us?

Comment: so this is my actual structure in body .I am using sample data but with actual structure.My version is .net core 3.1.I have edited in question with actual structure i am getting in body

Answer (score 1):

create a class with these two fields `id` and `name`

```
public class Item {
  public Int Id {get; set;}
  public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

and specify the type for your deserialized value:

```
dynamic body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
var rows = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(body["Response"]);
```

now you can use `rows.Count();`

Comment: It is throwing error.
The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.List<ShoppingSamples.Content.GoogleProductDetails>>(string)' has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know the amount of entries inside the `Response` collection then you can simply do that by making use of `JObject` and `JArray`:

```
string rawJson = ...;
JObject semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
JArray entries = (JArray)semiParsedJson["Response"];
int count = entries.Count;
```

Comment: I tried as u suggested but it is showing error.

 string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
             dynamic body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
      
          JObject semiParsedJson = JObject.Parsebody 
        JArray entries = (JArray)semiParsedJson["Response"];
         int count = entries.Count;
Unable to cast object of 
type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'.

Comment: @shashankshekhar That means the the copy-pasted response does not reflect to the reality. Could you please update?

Comment: data is coming as request body from data factory output of another function app as object type

Comment: @shashankshekhar In the provided sample the `Response` is a collection (`[]`), not an object (`{}`). Maybe I have autocorrected something when I've edited your question. Could you please overwrite it with the content of the `requestBody` variable?